# How to create an ArcMap Layer from a ArcGIS Map Service

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcmap

I would like to add an ILayer created from an ArcGIS Server Map service to an IMap with ArcObjects, but don't see how to do it.

I am getting an IMapServer3 with the following code, where mapName = the map service:

```
serverContext = som.CreateServerContext(mapName, "MapServer");
IServerObject serverObject = serverContext.ServerObject;
IMapServer3 mapServer = (IMapServer3)serverObject;
```

It looks like I can get an ILayer from an IMapServerGroupLayer, but it looks like the IMapServerGroupLayer is looking for a different connection type than I am using.

If you have an example of getting an ILayer from a Map Service, your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked...

```
private static void GetLayerFromMapServerLayer()
{

IAGSServerConnectionName servConnName = new AGSServerConnectionNameClass();
IPropertySet props = new PropertySetClass();
props.SetProperty("machine", "server");
servConnName.ConnectionProperties = props;



IAGSServerConnectionFactory pAGSServerConnectionFactory = new AGSServerConnectionFactoryClass();
IAGSServerConnection pAGSConnection = pAGSServerConnectionFactory.Open(props, 0);



IAGSEnumServerObjectName pEnumSOName = pAGSConnection.ServerObjectNames;

IAGSServerObjectName pSOName = pEnumSOName.Next();

while (pSOName != null)
{
if (pSOName.Name == "Base_Map")
break;
pSOName = pEnumSOName.Next();
}

IName pName = (IName)pSOName;
IMapServer mapServer = (IMapServer)pName.Open();

IMapServerLayer msLyr = new MapServerLayerClass();
msLyr.ServerConnect(pSOName, mapServer.DefaultMapName);

IMapServerGroupLayer group = (IMapServerGroupLayer)msLyr;

ILayer msLayer = (ILayer)msLyr;

//return msLayer;
MapDocument mapDoc = new MapDocumentClass();
mapDoc.Open(@"F:\~mkoneya~2011_82_13_58_30.mxd");
IMap myMap = mapDoc.get_Map(0);
myMap.AddLayer(msLayer);
mapDoc.Save();
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved your problem! Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted by clicking the check mark at left.